# Probability of light being refracted in deep space by H 2(Hydrogen)

Tags: classical-mechanics

Is it a valid question to ask what is the percentage of light that gets refracted by H 2 for a certain distance(Lets say 1 light year) in deep space.  Lets assume a few(3) Hydrogen atoms per cubic meter.

Comment: Sounds like a valid question to me... the astronomers might have a more "handy" answer for you, though. The problem I see for atomic hydrogen is that it has a really, really low cross section for frequencies that aren't within the line width of one of its transitions and the spectrum of molecular hydrogen is remarkably complex... I simply wouldn't know which of the many lines is of astronomical importance or if the way to "see" hydrogen clouds is by using a coarsely averaged spectrum and how to get that from first principles with absolute units...

Comment: @CuriousOne,  does 1.06 x10^-10 meter sound correct for collisional cross section for H 2.

Comment: BTW, Would the back of the envelope answer "It's roughly given by the index of refraction of hydrogen at normal conditions corrected for the density of space (a factor of roughly 4e-25, I believe)." work? In the visible that brings us to $n\approx 1 + 5*10^{-30}$.

Comment: @CuriousOne, that does make good sense your line of thinking.

Comment: Tho, its a dimensionless number, so thinking how I can apply it in answer.

Comment: It will slow down the effective speed of light and there would be lensing effects, if there are density variations... it's so small, though, even over cosmic distances.

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out by taking the collisional cross section(1.06 x10^-10m), the amount of linear meters in a light year( 9.46 x10 to 15 m). Multiply those two and then again by 3(number of atoms per meter cube). I get 3.06 x10 to 8 m cubed.

Comment: Where did you get that collisional cross section from? Are the units correct? Shouldn't that be an area?

Comment: Looked it up for Hydrogen 2, I will recheck the units. I found that odd, but that what they used for their calculations.  I cubed it in my thinking, tho.  I figured if I can take the number of atoms I would have in a light year of distance, multiply those and cube it for my area.  If they are randomly dispersed, I see no way of light not hitting a Hydrogen 2 atom.  Another variable, tho it shouldn't play a role, is how close a set of H2 can get(is there a gap in their H2 collisional cross section?), but for my calculation its dispersed over a cubic light year distance.

Comment: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Modeling_Reaction_Kinetics/Collision_Theory/Collisional_Cross_Section

Comment: Link I found the info, Step 3 of their work problem has the cross section of H2 in the answer part.

Comment: What cross section is it, though? Visible photons with H2 or H2 molecules hitting each other (that's usually what molecular cross sections are). Yep... that's for molecular collision, it's not a scattering cross section for light.

Comment: Photons with H2, is what I want to find. That is what I am mulling in my head where my thinking is wrong. Photon is another beast in this situation?(I don't know the treatment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34161/discussion-between-curiousone-and-ed-yablecki).